# selenium, error 10047 (Address family not supported), but working with try/catch (with workaround)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# and selenium. Everything was working okay, no problems.
Today when debugging my program in Visual Studio I get an error at this line:

```
this.WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(bin, profile);
```

The error ist:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.AddressFamilyNotSupported
ErrorCde 10047
```

The complete code I use is:

```
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary bin = new FirefoxBinary();
this.WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(bin, profile);
```

I have a work around for that:

```
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary bin = new FirefoxBinary();
try
{
    this.WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(bin, profile);
}
finally
{
}
```

I don't know why I have this error now, I have switched on some errors in options recently, maybe this is the reason.

What can I do? I don't want to just ignore this error, if I really don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be that you have a firewall that blocks your program? Can you disable it an test again?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the comodo firewall in use. But after deactivating it, the issue remains.

Comment: Comodo seems to have three different security levels (Firewall, Defense+, Sandbox). Did you disable all three?

Comment: I just clicked the comdoo icon and selected "closed" ("beenden"). But I will try it now on an different computer with no firewall installed. I will give an update in about 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Okay, I tested the same project on an different PC without any firewall. Also windows firewall was deactivated. Do you have any other tips I can try?

Comment: This might as well be a bug. Since Selenium is open source, you could grab the source and debug it.

Comment: And I would look a their bug tracker and file a bug.